# How to programatically select the data from GridView1's first row 4th column cell on page load and save it to a variable in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, subgurim-maps

I am new to asp.net and C# web application development.

My question is: I have a `GridView1` which is bound to a data source which is getting data from a SQL Server table.

`Gridview1` has these columns:

- select(default select available in gridview to select row)
- time
- customer
- address
- longitude (visible = false)
- latitude (visible = false)

This data is also filtered and sorted by a drop down list date

What I want to do is when my page load the value of latitude and longitude column first row value get assigned to my variable lat and lng

This is what I am writing, basically the lat and lng variable will be used in my another function:

```
        Double lat, lng;
        lat = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[4].Text);
        lng = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[1].Cells[5].Text);
        GLatLng latlong = new GLatLng(lat, lng);
        GMap1.setCenter(latlong, 10);
```

The following exception is thrown:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

The gridview data is never null it always has some data

Comment: I solved the problem , all i have to do was change the visisbility property  of latitude and longitude column to true

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you bind your gridview to a data source before accessing the row collection 
Gridview.Datasource =yourdatasource 
Gridview.bind();

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

`lat = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text);`

Because `Gridview Rows` and `Cells` are always start from **0**(Zero).

**OR**

best way is use [.findControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) Method of `Controls` like below.

`string lat = ((Label)GridView1.Rows[0].FindControl("labelID")).Text`

**But,** for above code you have to take `<asp:label>` in `<ItemTemplate>` in your `GridView`

Comment: now following exception occur , Input string was not in a correct format. in my database data type is float for both latitude and longitude field ,if this information add any details to you

Comment: You should debug and see the value in `GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text`

Comment: `SELECT shedule.latitude, shedule.address, shedule.longitude, shedule.customer, mapicon.icon, shedule.time FROM shedule CROSS JOIN mapicon WHERE (shedule.date = @date)          `                                      this is my sql query of DataSource from where i am fetching data for my GridView1 in  troubleshooting tips it is displaying ** when converting a string to DateTime , Parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object** ,